# Recursive method to build a vector

Tags: python, recursion

I have a simple recursive function:

```
def subTree(z,sublevels):

    if(z < sublevels):
        print "from z = ", z, " to z = ", z+1
        subTree(z+1,sublevels)
    else:
        print "z = ", z, " !"
```

this simply goes from z to sublevels, ex:

```
subTree(2, 6)
from z =  2  to z =  3
from z =  3  to z =  4
from z =  4  to z =  5
from z =  5  to z =  6
z =  6  !
```

Now, how can i make it so that the call to the function returns an ordered vector of z ?

(in the example it would be: z[2,3,4,5,6])

From keiv code :

```
def subTree(z,sublevels,a):
    a.append(z)
    if(z < sublevels):    
        subTree(z+1,sublevels,a)


a=[]
subTree(2,6,a)
```

Comment: thanks for thhe edit jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share keiv.fly's bias for a recursive function that returns a result:

```
def subTree(z, sublevels):
    result = [z]

    if z < sublevels:
        result += subTree(z + 1, sublevels)

    return result

a = subTree(2, 6)
```

It can be reduced to the slightly less efficient one-liner:

```
def subTree(z, sublevels):
    return [z] + (subTree(z + 1, sublevels) if z < sublevels else [])
```

and both can be modified to return a tuple instead of a list:

```
def subTree(z, sublevels):
    return (z,) + (subTree(z + 1, sublevels) if z < sublevels else ())
```

And we can easily reverse the order of the result, if desired:

```
def subTree(z, sublevels):
    return (subTree(z + 1, sublevels) if z < sublevels else ()) + (z,)
```

Returning:

```
(6, 5, 4, 3, 2)
```

If you want to pass the array into the function, then I suggest you still return it as a value as follows:

```
def subTree(z, sublevels, array):
    array += type(array)([z])

    if z < sublevels:
        array = subTree(z + 1, sublevels, array)

    return array
```

By doing `type(array)([z])`, and the explicit returns, we can make this function work for multiple data types:

```
a = []
a = subTree(2, 6, a)
print(a)

a = ()
a = subTree(2, 6, a)
print(a)

a = b""
a = subTree(ord('2'), ord('6'), a)
print(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
b'23456'
```

Comment: very in depth answer, approved !

Answer (score 0):

This code changes "a" list to [2,3,4,5,6]

```
def subTree(z,sublevels,a):
    a.append(z)
    if(z < sublevels):    
        subTree(z+1,sublevels,a)

a=[]
subTree(2,6,a)
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for ty

Comment: but isn't it a bit redundant ?

Comment: could you tell me the difference between your code and the one i edited ?

Comment: In your code you do not return a result. When you reach 6 the condition does not work and your code does not return anything. And Python is not a functional language: You need to explicitly state "return" otherwise the function returns nothing.

Comment: And the return before the subTree is needed to get the result back where you called the function. In recursion you go forward several steps and then you need to get back and return the result to the first call.

Comment: i don't return a result because the vector is given as a parameter and it's modified "on the go", if you execute my code, it seems to work

Comment: You are right the list is passed by reference and changed on the go. It was just that I prefer to have a return for a function when we actually need to return something. Here in the recursion the return adds a backward loop which is redundant here.